# Slurm wont run mpi Job with specific number of nodes

Tags: mpi, slurm

I am currenntly trying to run calculalations that require large amounts of memory per core on a HPC cluster.

I am using a single node/machine with 512 GB ram. I have 28 cores per machine, but every process needs more than 512/28 GB ram.

I have no issue using 12 or 2 processes (which means I don't saturate the node intentionally) but whenever I try to use 6 or 7 I get:

```
srun: error: node058: tasks 3-5: Exited with exit code 255
```

The relevant part of my slurm script is:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=6
#SBATCH --hint=nomultithread
#SBATCH --partition=mem512
#SBATCH --time=1008:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=NONE
#SBATCH --job-name=$NAME
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --export=NONE

export SLURM_EXPORT_ENV=ALL
export I_MPI_DEBUG=5
export I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libpmi.so.0


#set period as decimal point
export LC_NUMERIC=C

ulimit -s unlimited
ulimit -l hard


export TMPDIR=/scratch/$SLURM_JOB_USER/$SLURM_JOBID


srun --cpu-bind=cores  some_program  < input 1> $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/output 2>error
```

Thank you for reading,

Cheers!

Comment: run `dmesg` and looke for some messages related to the `oom-killer`.

Comment: this returns "dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: you will need to ask your sysadmin to do it then: `sudo dmesg`

Comment: is there really nothing that can be done without bothering someone?

Comment: this is just to confirm the root cause of the crash is an out of memory error. If you have little doubt about that, your options are adding memory to your node, using more nodes (and hence decrease the number of tasks per node), or rewrite your app (for example making it out-of-core to decrease the memory usage)